# What is the easiest way to search all useful files inside a single project?

Tags: search, project

**What is the easiest way to search for a regexp throughout the contents all files in the current project, skipping files that are not useful?**

Useless files are things like compiled files, imported libraries,
version-control files, etc.

I’m aware of `rgrep`, but it just searches everything. Is there a
package that searches ‘inteligently’ and knows about several
different programming languages, so I wouldn’t have to configure it
for each individual project?

Comment: Your "it just searches everything" comment about `rgrep` is a little confusing, given that it excludes all files matching your "useless files" criteria by default.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Project based searching within Emacs can be done using [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile).

It allows for per-project configuration of ignore files (in a `<projectroot>\.projectile` file), or specify subdirectories to monitor and ignore all others.

It can run `grep`, `ack` (requires `ack-and-a-half.el`) and `ag` (`ag.el`) on files within the defined project (either based on the `.projectile` file or by finding a supported VC file to define a project root).

#### Useful Commands

(With regards to searching through useful files)

As per Projectile Readme

- `C-c p s g`  :: Run `grep` on the files in the project.
- `C-c p s a`  :: Runs `ack` on the project. Requires the presence of ack-and-a-half.
- `C-c p s s`  :: Runs `ag` on the project. Requires the presence of ag.el.
- `C-c p f`    :: Display a list of all files in the project.
- `C-c p d`    :: Display a list of all directories in the project.
- `C-c p a`  :: Switch between files with the same name but different extension in the project.
- `C-c p o` :: Runs `multi-occur` on all project buffers currently open.

These will only act on files defined as being part of the project (or found when the cache is generated/regenerated).

Comment: Thanks, what's the projectile command that I can use for this?

Comment: Edited it to include a subset of the commands (those dealing with search, find-file and dired).  Full list is in the package readme.

Answer (score 14):

The project-wide search of only relevant files can be done using [`ag` aka the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher).

#### Why ag?

- It ignores file patterns from your `.gitignore`, `.hgignore`, `svn:ignore`. *You can choose for your searches to NOT use the ignore list from the version-control ignore lists by using the `-U` switch.*
- If there are files in your source repo you don't want to search, just add their patterns to a `.agignore` file.

  - A global `.agignore` file can be put in your `$HOME` and then you can put more project specific `.agignore` files in your project roots.

#### Setting up `ag` and emacs

- Install [`ag` aka the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) on your system.
- Set up the `.agignore` file. *I prefer to have just a global `.agignore` file in my `$HOME`.*
- Install the [`ag`](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el) package (available on Melpa).

  - I would also recommend installing the [`wgrep-ag`](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep/blob/master/wgrep-ag.el) package (also available on Melpa). That would help if and when you try to do [project-wide search/replace using `ag`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/243/115).
- You can then use the `ag-project` or `ag-project-regexp` function (that come with the `ag` package) to do project-wide file searches.

  - By default, these functions use the root of the VCS repo as the directory to search in. You can override this by setting or customizing the `ag-project-root-function`.
  - Even if your project is not git controlled, you can mark a project-root for the `ag-project` / `ag-project-regexp` based searches by putting an empty `.git` folder in your project root. You then don't have to customize `ag-project-root-function`.

Answer (score 8):

If your project uses Git, you only need `counsel` https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper

- `counsel-git` to find file
- `counsel-git-grep` to grep

The only dependency is git

Text grepping is faster than the silver searcher (ag)

Counsel also provides other powerful tools. For example, after running `counsel-git-grep`, you can press `C-c C-o` and `C-x C-q` to go into `wgrep-mode` to easily replace text in the project scope.

There is an article https://sam217pa.github.io/2016/09/11/nuclear-power-editing-via-ivy-and-ag/ explaining details. That article uses `counsel-ag` (another command built into counsel) but `cousnel-git-grep` uses exactly same work flow.

Comment: But how come text-grepping is faster than ag? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `ag` is also a grep program, like `git-grep`. I can't say which is faster. See https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep which compares the performance of popular grep programs (including `ag` and `git-grep`)

Comment: When I am using `counsel-git-grep`; can it recognize for example char `[` right away instead of typing it as `\[`

Comment: This is way better than projectile's grep, IMO

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is beautiful, but it leaves out some critical details about modern versions of Emacs. I am knew to Emacs myself, so other newcomers might not be aware of this. Given your goal is to search for text WITHIN a file in a PROJECT, then you would first install Projectile using the MELPA repository.

This installs the package in .emacs.d and adds some basic configuration to .emacs in your $USER directory (assuming you had created the .emacs file), such as requiring Projectile in your Emacs install.

However, you still need to enable it and associate keymap prefixes, so you can invoke it in the mini buffer.

The accepted answer mentions the following command:

```
C-c p s g
```

This will not work, unless you configure Projectile with this keymap prefix. But I configured it to use C-c C-p as the command for Project in .emacs:

```
(projectile-mode +1)
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-p") 'projectile-command-map)
```

Now given this, I am able to perform text searches in files in a project using grep:

```
C-c C-p f # switch to a project first
C-c C-p s g # perform grep search in project
```

To break it down,  `C-c C-p` will invoke Projectile, and `s g` will perform the grep search. You will get a beautiful output like this, assuming your search is `visit_contact` and you are searching Ruby's rspec in a project:

```
./spec/support/capybara_classification_code_helper.rb:21:  def visit_contact
./spec/features/admin_edits_classification_code_role_dynamic_field_spec.rb:8:    visit_contact
./spec/features/admin_edits_classification_code_role_dynamic_field_spec.rb:33:    visit_contact
./spec/features/user_views_global_filters_from_line_item_spec.rb:9:      visit_contact
```

Answer (score 1):

`M-x` `rgrep` `search-pattern` `*.[c,h]`