# Color declared variables

Tags: font-lock, colors, c++, variables

I'm looking for a simple way to make emacs remember of declared variable in a single function in C/C++. By "simple", I mean without any external package, just with some elisp lines in configuration files.

My default Emacs configuration colors variables names in yellow on declaration, but let them white on use.

```
char toto; // 'char' is green, 'toto' is yellow

toto = 42; // 'toto' is white
```

I would like to make every "toto" of the same function/scope colored in yellow as well.

I've already looked on [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/474/using-emacs-as-a-full-featured-c-c-ide) but I would like something simpler. I also tried to do something with [font-lock mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Mode.html), but I didn't succeed to make something adaptable to variable names.

I already have an idea for C++ class member names (using a name pattern), so I just want a local variable match here.

Comment: This is probably harder than it looks. http://www.nobugs.org/developer/parsingcpp/

Comment: Why don't you want to use any packages? If there is a package that provides this feature, installing it will almost certainly require less elisp in your config than re-creating the feature from scratch.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the [`color-identifiers-mode` package](https://github.com/ankurdave/color-identifiers-mode).  (Posting this as a comment because you said you didn't want to consider external packages.)

Comment: Every "external package" can also be described as "some elisp lines in configuration files". Avoiding pre-existing code on the basis that someone has provided it in package form is absurd.

Comment: What version of Emacs do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You could muster a regexp for your variable scheme, something that matches (pseudo regexp code)`[char|other|types] [a-z];` and `[a-z] =*;` and add it to the font-lock keyword list for your mode ; From the manual at [the Customizing-Keywords page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customizing-Keywords.html) :

> For example, the following code adds two fontification patterns for C
>   mode: one to fontify the word ‘FIXME’, even in comments, and another
>   to fontify the words ‘and’, ‘or’ and ‘not’ as keywords.

```
 (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
  '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)
    ("\\<\\(and\\|or\\|not\\)\\>" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

> This example affects only C mode proper. To add the same patterns to C
>   mode and all modes derived from it, do this instead:

```
 (add-hook 'c-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
   (font-lock-add-keywords nil
    '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)
      ("\\<\\(and\\|or\\|not\\)\\>" .
       font-lock-keyword-face)))))
```