# find-grep-dired equivalents for ack and ag

Tags: search, dired, files, projectile

Is there an equivalent `find-grep-dired` using `ack` or `ag`? With the ability to specify the directory where the search starts? The Dired output itself is not so important (in fact I prefer the *ack-mode* result output). The closest thing I found is a Projectile `ag`/`ack` integration where the prefix argument prompts for the directory, but I was looking for something more general.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by more general? The way this question is phrased now makes it unrelated to emacs.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Here is another try : the projectile ag/ack integration supports prefix argument, which when used prompts for the directory. So it works similar to the _find-grep-dired_. But that works only within a projectile project (projectile mode is on). I'm looking for ag/ack version of _find-grep-dired_ that can be used _outside_ of the projectile too.

Answer (score 2):

The `ag` package (available on MELPA) has the ability to run `ag` only within your specified folder or in project root. Check out its [README](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el#running-a-search) on its github for more info.

Here are some of the answers from this stackexchange the elaborate on the use of `ag` in emacs:

- [What is the easiest way to search all useful files inside a single project?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/453/115)
- [Is there a way to use query-replace from grep/ack/ag output modes?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/243/115)

Answer (score 2):

Here is small function that does what I was looking for; perhaps useful to someone else too. The function prompts for the directory and invokes the `ag` `search-term`. When invoked with the prefix argument the `search-term` is interpreted as regular expression.

```
(defun find-ag (dir search-term)
  "Run an ag search with SEARCH-TERM in the directory.

With an optional prefix argument ARG SEARCH-TERM is interpreted as a
regular expression."
  (interactive "DFind-ag (directory): \nsFind-ag (ag expression): ")
  (if (fboundp 'ag-regexp)
      (let ((ag-command (if current-prefix-arg 'ag-regexp 'ag))
            ;; reset the prefix arg, otherwise it will affect the ag-command
            (current-prefix-arg nil))
        (funcall ag-command search-term dir))
    (error "Ag is not available")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [helm-ff-do-grep invoked in helm-find-files](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-8) to grep any directory you want. It has a demo in there; the grep in Helm is incremental: it returns results for every character you type, effectively provides live feedback. Or use `helm-projectile` that is capable of invoking grep in any directory of selected file or directory in a helm-projectile-find-file or helm-projectile-find-dir. See the [helm-projectile guide here](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html).