# How to convert lines to an org-mode checklist?

Tags: org-mode

Suppose I have the following list.  I'd like to convert it to a checklist.

```
Lec 1 |         1:20:36
Lec 2 |         1:10:32
Lec 3 |         1:08:33
Lec 4 |         1:20:33
Lec 5 |         1:16:50
Lec 6 |         1:08:49
Lec 7 |         1:17:40
Lec 8 |         1:19:47
Lec 9 |         1:21:22
Lec 10 |        1:23:52
Lec 11 |        1:23:45
Lec 12 |        1:25:32
Lec 13 |        1:19:06
Lec 14 |        1:14:28
Lec 15 |        1:11:01
Lec 16 |        1:24:07
Lec 17 |        1:24:34
Lec 18 |        1:17:17
Lec 19 |        1:14:59
Lec 22 |        1:15:08
Lec 23 |        1:16:48
Lec 24 |        1:24:47
Lec 25 |        1:25:21
```

How to do it?

(I did it in using kbd-macro. I wonder is there an `org` command to do it?)

Comment: There are many ways and the quickness is subjective. I would use `multiple cursors` or `query-search-replace`. By converting to check list, you mean to simply prepend the lines with `[ ]`, correct?

Comment: Yes. Can you briefly show how to use `multiple cursors` or `query-search-replace`?

Comment: Here's a [detailed explanation](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/243/115) of how to use `multiple-cursors` for doing search-replace. That would apply to this case too.

Comment: Quick web searches bring up the links to [`multiple-cursors`](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) and the manual page on [Query Replace](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html).  A lot of this stuff is really well documented, and is just a web search away.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be advanced and a little complex. I need to get familiar with those command/tools.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simplest way I could think of:

1. Select the list.
2. Move the point to the first column.
3. <kbd>C-x r t</kbd>`- [ ]`<kbd>RET</kbd>

You are done.

Comment: Wow! The rectangle editing is so straight forward yet powerful! Thank you!

Comment: Such awesome. Very useful for conversion of checklists.

Answer (score 21):

Vanilla org-mode:

- `C-c -` (`org-ctrl-c-minus`) - Convert selected text into a plain list
- `C-u C-c C-x C-b` (`org-toggle-checkbox`) - Convert selected plain list into a list with checkboxes

Spacemacs:

- `, -` (`org-ctrl-c-minus`) - Convert selected text into a plain list
- `SPC u , T c` (`org-toggle-checkbox`) - Convert selected plain list into a list with checkboxes

Answer (score 11):

First, some semantics for clarity.  In `org-mode`, a [*plain list*](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#Plain-lists) is either ordered or unordered, starting with either a `-`, `+`, or `*` (for unordered), or a number followed by either a `.` or a `)` (for ordered).  So: the "list" you describe in your example is not yet an `org-mode` list, because it doesn't start with any of these bullets.

Second, I presume by "checklist" you mean the [checkboxes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html) that `org-mode` uses in its plain lists, as in:

```
- [X] A checked list item
- [ ] An unchecked list item
```

Here's a very simple function that will convert all lines in the selected region to an unordered list with checkboxes (not extensively tested, but works on your example):

```
(defun org-convert-lines-to-checklist (beg end)
  "Convert all plain lines in region to a plain list with
checkboxes."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (dotimes (_ (- (line-number-at-pos end) (line-number-at-pos beg)))
      (insert "- [ ] ")
      (indent-according-to-mode)
      (forward-line 1))))
```

Answer (score 9):

Below is another **fun** way to transform text into an `org-mode` checklist.

**Use Org-mode Code Blocks to Convert Text into List of Checkboxes**

> Note: To generate the results use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> while the cursor is within a code block.
>   Then answer `yes` when prompted.

1. Wrap your list inside a named dynamic block

   ```
   #+NAME: my-list-block  
   #+BEGIN:  
   Lec 1 |         1:20:36'  
   Lec 2 |         1:10:32  
   Lec 3 |         1:08:33  
   Lec 4 |         1:20:33  
        ... More ...  
   Lec 24 |        1:24:47  
   Lec 25 |        1:25:21  
   #+END:
   ```
2. Write an `org-mode` code block in your favorite programming language.

   **Example 1** - Using an `elisp` Code Block

   ```
   #+name: list-into-checklist-elisp
   #+header: :results list raw replace output 
   #+header: :var data=my-list-block()
   #+begin_src elisp
     (dolist (x (split-string data "\n"))
           (princ (format "[ ] %s\n" x)))
   #+end_src

   #+RESULTS: list-into-checklist-elisp
   - [ ] Lec 1 |         1:20:36
   - [ ] Lec 2 |         1:10:32
   - [ ] Lec 3 |         1:08:33
   - [ ] Lec 4 |         1:20:33
   - [ ]       ... More ...
   - [ ] Lec 24 |        1:24:47
   - [ ] Lec 25 |        1:25:21
   ```

   **Example 2** - Using a `perl` Code Block

   ```
   #+name: list-into-checklist-perl
   #+header: :results list raw replace output
   #+header: :var data=my-list-block()
   #+begin_src perl
     map { printf qq([ ] %s\n), $_ } split(/\n/, $data); 
   #+end_src

   #+RESULTS: list-into-checklist-perl
   - [ ] Lec 1 |         1:20:36
   - [ ] Lec 2 |         1:10:32
   - [ ] Lec 3 |         1:08:33
   - [ ] Lec 4 |         1:20:33
   - [ ]       ... More ...
   - [ ] Lec 24 |        1:24:47
   - [ ] Lec 25 |        1:25:21
   ```

   **Example 3** - Using a `bash` Code Block

   ```
   #+name: list-into-checklist-bash
   #+header: :results list raw replace output
   #+header: :shebang #!/usr/bin/env bash
   #+header: :var data=my-list-block()
   #+begin_src sh
     while IFS="\n" read -ra ADDR; do
           for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
               echo "[X] $i"
           done
      done <<< "$data"
   #+end_src

   #+RESULTS: list-into-checklist-bash
   - [X] Lec 1 |         1:20:36
   - [X] Lec 2 |         1:10:32
   - [X] Lec 3 |         1:08:33
   - [X] Lec 4 |         1:20:33
   - [X]       ... More ...
   - [X] Lec 24 |        1:24:47
   - [X] Lec 25 |        1:25:21
   ```

   **Example 4** - Using a `python` Code Block

   ```
   #+name: list-into-checklist-python
   #+header: :results list raw replace output
   #+header: :var data=my-list-block()
   #+Begin_src python
     l = ["[ ] {x}".format(x=row) for row in data.splitlines()]
     for i in l: print i
   #+end_src 

   #+RESULTS: list-into-checklist-python
   - [ ] Lec 1 |         1:20:36
   - [ ] Lec 2 |         1:10:32
   - [ ] Lec 3 |         1:08:33
   - [ ] Lec 4 |         1:20:33
   - [ ]       ... More ...
   - [ ] Lec 24 |        1:24:47
   - [ ] Lec 25 |        1:25:21
   ```

   **Example 5** - Using a `ruby` Code Block

   ```
   #+name: list-into-checklist-ruby
   #+header: :results list raw replace output
   #+header: :var data=my-list-block()
   #+Begin_src ruby
     for l in  data.split("\n")
       puts "[ ] #{l}"
     end
   #+end_src 

   #+RESULTS: list-into-checklist-ruby
   - [ ] Lec 1 |         1:20:36
   - [ ] Lec 2 |         1:10:32
   - [ ] Lec 3 |         1:08:33
   - [ ] Lec 4 |         1:20:33
   - [ ]       ... More ...
   - [ ] Lec 24 |        1:24:47
   - [ ] Lec 25 |        1:25:21
   ```

Thanks for asking your question!

Hope that helped!

Note: This code was tested using the following versions of emacs and org-mode.

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1343.14)
Org-mode version 8.2.10 (8.2.10-29-g89a0ac-elpa)
```

Answer (score 7):

Using search and replace:

<kbd>M-%</kbd>Lec <kbd>Enter</kbd>  - [ ] Lec  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that there are spaces around the checkbox, although they don't show up well here.

Comment: This also works very well. Sorry I can only mark one as the answer, so I can only vote up. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

In [Evil mode](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/wiki/Home) or [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/) you can do this, assuming you have not changed the default key-bindings:

1. In Normal state (equivalent to Vim's Normal mode), move the cursor to the beginning of the **first** line in your list.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>j</kbd> once for each **remaining** line in your list. *(Alternatively, type the number of remaining lines in your list, followed by the <kbd>j</kbd> key. E.g. for your example: <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.)*
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.
5. Type `- [ ]`.
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

For short, `C-u C-c C-c` on the first item of a list can turn the whole list into checklist.

[Checkboxes (The Org Manual)](https://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html) says

> `C-c C-c` (`org-toggle-checkbox`)
>
> Toggle checkbox status or — with prefix argument — checkbox presence at point.
>
> - With a single prefix argument, add an empty checkbox or remove the current one.
> - With a double prefix argument, set it to ‘[-]’, which is considered to be an intermediate state.

There is a note on the single prefix argument:

> `C-u C-c C-c` on the *first* item of a list with no checkbox adds checkboxes to the rest of the list.