# Org-mode: How do you carry over incomplete todo items?

Tags: org-mode

I use the following to keep track of my daily tasks/todos etc:

```
** Monday 03.10.2016 [7/18]...
** Tuesday 04.10.2016
       CLOCK: [2016-10-04 Di. 09:00]
Some things to do...
```

How would I carry over the open tasks from Monday to Tuesday's block in org-mode?

Comment: Here is something similar that I use to carry forward uncompleted tasks:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5700/2287  You can modify it to suit your needs.  I have setup a prompt when I load my master todo file that asks me whether I wish to reorganize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't sort my tasks into hierarchical structures by hand but use the aggregation via org-agenda.

- [org manual TODO-Items](http://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-Items.html)
- [Sachas WIP intro "A Baby Steps Guide to Managing Your Tasks with Org"](http://emacslife.com/baby-steps-org.html)

Judging from your presented lines, the entries under Monday are checkboxed lists or TODO childs.

Coming from checkbox lists I'd sort by reverse checked state with `org-sort (C-c ^) X`, convert the open entries to Todo child entries `org-list-make-subtree (C-c C-*)`, mark the open lines by hand and refile the region to the running clock task `org-refile (C-u 2 C-c C-w)` when the Tuesday task is clocked in. If your child entries are already todo child entries the argument for `org-sort` changes to `todo order (o)` or its capital version.

You can change TODO children back to checkbox lists with `org-ctrl-c-minus (C-c -)`

I have not yet found out how to move a list of checkbox entries if the cut and paste is not done by hand. If you're willing to do that, sort the list, cut the interesting stuff and `org-clock-jump-to-running-clock` and paste.

Comment: The hierarchical set is purely used to keep a log of my daily activities, as it happens, with significant rollover in places. In this context I do not use org-agenda.

I'll get back to you on your answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reverse sort shortcut. (-> TIL).

If there is a select unchecked option, perhaps I can somehow automate this into a single shortcut step. Looks like I'll have to revert to elisp for this.