# Is there any way to postpone or update all expired deadlines (or scheduled tasks) at once?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

*Is there any way to postpone or update all expired deadlines (or scheduled tasks) at once in org-agenda mode?*

I tend to schedule more than I can handle and need a way to quickly either (a) remove old deadlines or (b) postpone old deadlines. (It would be nice to have a similar tool for the "SCHEDULED" property as well.)

Comment: Here is an example of how to change the date for all tasks/events matching a certain criteria -- I use it to carry forward all uncompleted tasks:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5700/2287  For example, I have 25 things that are due today -- I wake up tomorrow morning and open up my org-mode file and am greeted by a yes/no prompt -- "Carry forward uncompleted todo?"  I say yes, and presto!  If I have already done it, then I just say no.  The example uses `org-deadline` to change a DEADLINE date, but you can also use `org-schedule` to change a SCHEDULED date.

Comment: Sadly, the built-in functions `org-agenda-schedule` and `org-agenda-deadline` do *not* appear to have the ability to act upon a selected region.  However, the built-in functions `org-schedule` and `org-deadline` already have the ability to act upon a selected region. So, the original poster can just use those commands in a regular org-mode buffer on a selected region of tasks/events that need changing.