# How to configure org-mode properly after upgrading from 7.9.3

Tags: org-mode, variables, upgrade

[On the orgmode site](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-8.0.html) it says that if you upgrade from org-mode v.7.9.4f to v.8+:

> You must search your configuration for the existence of varaibles starting with org-export- and change their names (e.g. `org-export-html-validation-link` is now `org-html-validation-link`).

My question is, how do I do that? If I do a <kbd>C-h v</kbd> and look for `org-export-`, I do see a long list of variables with names that apparently need changing. What do I do next?

Comment: I believe what that means is that you need to look in your init file for places where you've set the `org-export-...` variables and change their names in that init file so that whatever customizations you've made will be recognized.

Comment: Consult the variable `user-init-file` if you don't know the location of your init file.

Comment: You may not need to do anything if you didn't set those variables yourself at some point. Is something not working after your upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your emacs config by using the `wgrep` mode (package available through Melpa). If you don't know where you might have used the old variables, this approach will help if you at least know which folder holds your emacs configuration.

Check out the solutions to this emacs.SE question on [Is there a way to use query-replace from grep/ack/ag output modes?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/212/115).

Here is the summary of steps needed fix your emacs config with old `org-mode` variables:

- Figure out the folder containing all your emacs config
- Do recursive search of the old variables in that folder using a tool of your choice: `grep`, `ag`, etc; you can do that from within emacs as demonstrated in the above link.
- Replace the old variables in the result with the new variables and save the edits by making use of `wgrep` (or `wgrep-ag`, etc) as demonstrated in the above link.

Comment: My '.emacs' file and my '.emacs.d' folder are in '~/'. I'll assume that's the folder you mean and give this suggestion a try.

Comment: One may need also need to check customization files.

Comment: @BrianZ If you have a `~/.emacs.d` folder I would suggest doing `\mv ~/.emacs ~/.emacs.d/init.el` so that everything related to emacs config stays in a single folder. Then you can do recursive search/replace just in `~/.emacs.d`.

Answer (score 1):

When I followed kaushalmodi's suggestion, I found that the unwanted variables were being set in my *new* org-mode installation. This lead me to realize that the installation must have gone horribly wrong.

I deleted the `org` package in `package-list-packages`, backed up my `.emacs` file, wiped out any lines in it that were in any way even potentially related to org-mode, and redid the installation. Now everything looks right, as far as I can tell.