# How can I edit the Helm results buffer and have the changes reflected in the original buffers?

Tags: helm, replace

I've seen this demonstrated before in various screencasts and can't find it searching through the docs. I do use `helm-swoop-edit` quite often in a single buffer but when I need to change all occurrences across a project it gets a bit tedious.

For bonus points if there is a utility function to build such a buffer from *helm* results? I'd be very interested as my general project searching methods are `helm-git-grep`, `helm-do-grep` and `helm-do-ag`.

Comment: *If not using helm*, `ag` + *multiple cursors* / `query-replace-regexp` can [do a very good job](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/243/115).

Comment: @kaushalmodi: ahh wgrep-mode is what I want. M-x `helm-git-grep`, action [f3] "Save results to grep buffer", wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's documented in helm's wiki: [8.10. Save grep session](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#810-save-grep-session), when using `helm-occur`/`helm-do-grep`/`helm-do-ag`, you can use <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> to save search result to buffer, after installing `wgrep-helm`, you can use [wgrep's commands](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep#usage) to edit that buffer.