# Using Occur to to recursively search in a directory

Tags: search, replace, occur

I use 'occur' to search for regexp in current buffer and edit the results in *occur* buffer .

Now my requirement is to search all the files in a directory(including sub-directories ) and edit the results.

ie. Edit the result of ' grep -r foo * '

Is there anything similar(like *occur* buffer) that allows to edit the searched results in my case.

Comment: Searching recursively or searching multiple files (anywhere). The question is not too clear. How do you want to specify the set of files to search? See, for example, command `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers`.

Comment: Set of files  from command:   ' grep -r foo * '. I have updated my question.

Comment: It seems this question has been asked earlier, but differently . https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/212/is-there-a-way-to-use-query-replace-from-grep-ack-ag-output-modes?rq=1 .

Answer (score 1):

[Elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep) allows you to grep files in a directory and recursively in its sub-directories.
It lists the found matches in an `*elgrep*` buffer (much like occur).

New users should input the search data in the `*elgrep-menu*` buffer opened by the command <kbd>M-x</kbd> `elgrep-menu` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

The minor mode `elgrep-edit-mode` can be toggled on through the menu item `Elgrep -> Elgrep-edit` in the `*elgrep*` buffer it is also bound to the key sequence <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>. The user experience in editing the `*elgrep*` buffer is a bit different from that one editing the `*occur*` buffer.The edits are not performed instantaneous in the corresponding file buffer but you save the edits in the `*elgrep*` buffer with `save-buffer` (normally bound to <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>) when you are done.
The edits in the `*elgrep*` buffer are applied to the files with the matches on `save-buffer`.

## Remarks:

- You can install [elgrep via melpa](https://melpa.org/#/elgrep). If you have [registered correctly `melpa` in `package-archives`](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started) you just call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `elgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd>.
- You can use the option `Run asynchronously` in the `*elgrep-menu*` buffer even if that one is marked as `experimentally`. I use it for years now and it is rock-solid. The only drawback is the weak feedback if no matches are found. It just prints a message `No matches found` in the echo area.
- If you save the edits from the `*elgrep*` buffer elgrep checks whether it finds the old matches in the listed files. It does not apply the edit for a match if it does not find the old match. This is a measure of caution. It has the drawback that you can/should not edit and save matches multiple times without a new run of `elgrep`.
- You can edit the matched texts in the `*elgrep*` buffer but you cannot edit the file names or the line numbers for the matches. They are protected with the `read-only` text property.

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Tobias's answer, there's already a built-in `rgrep` which does much the same.  It uses the grep binary though.

Comment: `rgrep` doesn't allow editing in the results buffer like OP asked for.